# push_back() causes program to stop before entering main()

Tags: c++, microcontroller, stm32, keil

I'm developing in c++ for my STM32F3 Discovery board and using std::deque as queue. After trying to debug my code (directly on device with ST-link or in simulator), the code eventually stops at breakpoint before even entering my code in main(). However, SystemInit() configures board just fine..

I've traced this behavior down to using push_back() (and push_front) as commenting it out from code solves the issue. Through disassmebly I found that after using it, the execution stops at breakpoint instruction BKPT and won't move further after resuming execution. This instruction is part of _sysopen() call, with call path:

```
__main -> __scatterload -> __scatterload_null -> __rt_entry -> __rt_lib_init -> __rt_lib_init_atexit_1 -> _initio -> freopen -> _sysopen
```

What intrigues me is call to `_initio`, which is missing if push_back isn't used, because there is no `__rt_lib_init_atexit_1`. Introducing push_back also makes the code size go from 10 kB to 34 kB.

Might this be a result of some bad configuration or should I try another IDE? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you show something of the actual C++ code? The fact that removing one line prevents the failure doesn't mean necessarily that the error is in that line.

Comment: @Antonio Sure, have a look: https://gist.github.com/BetaRavener/5957167 .

Uncommenting any of push_back lines causes this.

Comment: What about the declaration of scale_buffer?

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated the repo so there's now header also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I learnt it has something to do with so called 'semihosting' and
that I should build with my project file 'retarget.c' that contains definitions of the 
functions like '_sys_xxxx()' that are target specific driver level functions 
(many versions of 'retarget.c' are part of the Keil-MDK and also ca be found on web). 
So I did but then linker thrown errors similar to this:

```
Error: L6200E: Symbol _sys_open multiply defined (by arm_xxx_lib.o and retarget.o)
Error: L6200E: Symbol _sys_close multiply defined (by arm_xxx_lib.o and retarget.o)
...
```

I solved this by editing original 'retarget.c' so that functions defined in it will
override the ones in Keil-MDK libraries. The new 'retarged.c' is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rt_misc.h>

#pragma import(__use_no_semihosting_swi)

#include <rt_sys.h>

extern void $Super$$_sys_open(void);

FILEHANDLE $Sub$$_sys_open(const char *name, int openmode)
{
 return 1; /* everything goes to the same output */
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_close(void);
int $Sub$$_sys_close(FILEHANDLE fh)
{
 return 0;
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_write(void);
int $Sub$$_sys_write(FILEHANDLE fh, const unsigned char *buf,
              unsigned len, int mode)
{
 //your_device_write(buf, len);
 return 0;
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_read(void);
int $Sub$$_sys_read(FILEHANDLE fh, unsigned char *buf,
             unsigned len, int mode)
{
 return -1; /* not supported */
}

extern void $Super$$_ttywrch(void);
void $Sub$$_ttywrch(int ch)
{
 char c = ch;
 //your_device_write(&c, 1);
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_istty(void);
int $Sub$$_sys_istty(FILEHANDLE fh)
{
 return 0; /* buffered output */
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_seek(void);
int $Sub$$_sys_seek(FILEHANDLE fh, long pos)
{
 return -1; /* not supported */
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_flen(void);
long $Sub$$_sys_flen(FILEHANDLE fh)
{
 return -1; /* not supported */
}

extern void $Super$$_sys_exit(void);
long $Sub$$_sys_exit(FILEHANDLE fh)
{
 return -1; /* not supported */
}
```

With this version of 'retarget.c' linker was satisfied and my program run w/o problem.
Maybe this will help you as well.

Comment: This is a solution when continuing to use Keil, however because of this problem I later switched to Eclipse and building with an ARM specific toolchain: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded .

Comment: @francek Thanks. Helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by checking if scale_buffer contains any element (`scale_buffer.empty()`) before calls to `.back()` and `.front()`: you are probably reading and writing some garbage, which makes the deque invalid, preparing the ground for a crash when you call `push_back()`

Comment: The problem is I don't get to call back/front. And if I would (push_back commented out) I end up with HardFault interrupt, so this is not solution

Comment: @Raven What is the return value of scale_buffer.empty()?

Comment: logically if I don't push anything, then true (practically too). Man I'm not a beginner.

Comment: @Raven What I see is (for example) `scale_buffer.back().second > 0`: if the buffer is empty how does that check make sense?

Comment: you're analyzing my concept rather than solving this issue. That buffer is supposed to have at least one item in it at each time (pushed in constructor, never popped, doesn't mean it will be the same item forever). However if push isn't working, that code is going to have lots of problems like this, but it's not what I want to solve.

Comment: @Raven Can you confirm that if you uncomment  just `scale_buffer.push_back(std::make_pair(gyroInit.Full_Scale, 0));` in the constructor you get the crash?

Comment: It's not crash, it's getting stuck at some breakpoint inside sysopen, and I don't really know what or why is it calling