# Not able to add C++ libraries in keil c project

Tags: c++, c, arm, keil

I am trying to add a c++ library to a c project in keil.
Code is getting compiled and linked properly, but i am not able to debug as it is not reaching main.It is getting stopped at a function *sys_open* exactly at *BKPT 0xAB* instruction.
I tried posting in keil forum.

http://www.keil.com/forum/59982/#msg195240

I think it is related to *semihosting* in arm. 
I tried using no semi hosting and re-implemented following functions in **retarget.c**.
But I am getting a linker error that sys_open is multiply defined.

```
Error: L6200E: Symbol _sys_open multiply defined (by sys_io.o and retarget.o).
```

I am removing the definition I am getting the following linker error.

```
.\Objects\STM32429I_EVAL.axf: Error: L6915E: Library reports error: __use_no_semihosting was requested, but _sys_open was referenced
```

What mistake am I doing??

The lib file which i have added to the project makes use of assert functions.
If that is the problem, how can i re-implement assert in retarget?

Answer (score 0):

[push_back() causes program to stop before entering main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548453/push-back-causes-program-to-stop-before-entering-main#comment50773218_20777139)

I got answer from the above link. Please mark question as duplicate.